# incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to org.json.JSONArray

Tags: java

I am writing a Java function that restructures some JSON I am getting from a server and I am running into an issue trying to create a JSONArray:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonObj.getJSONObject("facet_counts").getJSONObject("facet_fields");
Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
jsonStr = jsonStr + "\"facetCounts\": {";
    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next();
        jsonStr = jsonStr + "\"" + key + "\":";
        if (jsonObject.get(key) instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray facets = jsonObject.get(key);
```

I am checking if jsonObject.get(key) is an instanceof JSONArray, but it keeps throwing the error `incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to org.json.JSONArray`.

Comment: Please read the Javadoc for JSONObject. You need to call `getJSONArray`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @tgdavies for their comment, was able to get it working by doing this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonObj.getJSONObject("facet_counts").getJSONObject("facet_fields");
Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
    jsonStr = jsonStr + "\"facetCounts\": {";
    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next();
        jsonStr = jsonStr + "\"" + key + "\":";
        if (jsonObject.get(key) instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray facets = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getJSONArray(key).toString());
```